Can't set warning / critical thresholds in munin plugin-conf.d file
For some reason, I cannot get warning thresholds to work on any of my munin installations on ubuntu. For example, one of the provided plugins I have working is the netstat plugin. Now to set the warning limit I have created a plugin file in /etc/munin/plugin-conf.d/zLast:
[netstat]
env.netstat.active.warning 3
env.active.warning 6

After restarting munin-node, there are no thresholds on the web interface or in the config output of munin-run netstat config. I do however see the environment variable commented out in the output of: munin-run -d netstat. This doesn't really help as this doesn't actually set any limit. Looking at the netstat plugin, it is a shell script plugin and it does contain calls for 'print_warning' and 'print_critical' for each value. Not sure what else I'm missing.
